# How do you create a capped collection using mongoose?

Tags: collections, mongoose

I'm trying to create a capped collection using Mongoose, however the following creates a collection that is not capped:

```js
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    Name: { type: String },
    Text: { type: String }
},
{
    capped: { max: 5, size: 1000000 }
});
```

I'm pretty sure I'm following the documentation's example properly, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: That the correct syntax; what version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: Code does look OK. Maybe the collection was already created as uncapped before you set the capped property. If so try dropping the collection, it should then get created as capped.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide max and size both or only max will be okay ?

Answer (score 8):

```
new Schema({..}, { capped: { size: 1024, max: 1000, autoIndexId: true } });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
new Schema({..}, { capped: { size: 1024, max: 1000, autoIndexId: true } });
```

- `size` is the maximum bytes in memory till which your database is not capped or till which your older records are not removed.
- `max` defines the number of maximum records which database will hold before capping.

  You must define size component irrespective of max component.
  Because if your size is used before reaching max then too capping will start but vice versa is not true.

Comment: so i can omit "max" and only specify size? how can i size a mongo db document with strings, ints and an objectId

Answer (score 0):

If non-capped collection already exist then you need to convert it to capped collection using following command.

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "collection_name", size: 100000});
```

Then you can able to use it with mongoose.